# Web-forms Initialize services in Page_Init

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, webforms, refactoring

My project is separated by Model,Services,DAO repository,Unity and Web forms part.In my page I have many hidden dependency and I want to refactoring code.

In my project i have many of this

```
        private DealsService dealsService;
        private DealsParser dealParser;
        private PeopleBinder peopleBinder;
        private DealStatusService dealStatusService;
        private PersonsService personService;
        private PersonalMetricsService metricService;
        private DealRelationsService dealRealtionService;
        private AuditReportService auditService;
        private ProductLineService productLineService;
        private DealProductLineService dealProdLineService;
        private DynamicColumnsService dynamicColService;
        private DealValuesService dealValuesService;

 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dealsService = new DealsService();
            peopleBinder = new PeopleBinder();
            dealParser = new DealsParser();
            dealStatusService = new DealStatusService();
            editDealId = Request.Params["ID"];
            FinancialPeriod = Request.Params["FinancialPeriod"];
            editFYandMonth = FinancialPeriod.Substring(2,7);
            editCountry = Request.Params["Country"];
            personService = new PersonsService();
            metricService = new PersonalMetricsService();
            dealRealtionService = new DealRelationsService();
            employeeService = new EmployeeService();
            auditService = new AuditReportService();
            productLineService = new ProductLineService();
            reports = new List<AuditReport>();
            dealProdLineService = new DealProductLineService();
            dynamicColService = new DynamicColumnsService();
            dealValuesService = new DealValuesService();
           }
```

Now Im starting to refactoring the code and create Interface for all this Services and encapsulated by Interface.If is possible to avoid this **new** keyword?Now I`m implement IoC container.

Answer (score 1):

Of course with dependency injection you can do this instead:

```
private IDealsService DealsService {get; set;}
private IDealsParser DealParser {get; set;}
//etc...

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e, IDealsService dealsService, IDealsParser dealParser)
{
    DealsService = dealsService;
    DealParser = dealParser;
    //etc...
}
```

And in your DI config whichever you decide to use. This is a Ninject example, set up the bindings:

```
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IDealsService>().To<DealsService>();
        Bind<DealsParser>().To<DealsParser>();
    }
}
```

A nice tutorial with Ninject http://blog.agilistic.nl/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-ninject-for-dependancy-injection-in-c-sharp/